# python spur reboot command not working

Tags: python, paramiko

I am using python 3.4.3 and using spur v0.3.15 ( a wrapper for paramiko), to SSH into a remote box.

For most commands its working fine, however I've encountered a few where its not.

The following command is meant to issue a reboot on the remote device, I get no error, but the device also doesn't reboot.

```
shell.run(["echo", password, "|", "sudo", "-S", "shutdown", "-r", "now"])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From spur documentation at:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/spur

**Why don’t shell features such as variables and redirection work?**

---

Commands are run directly rather than through a shell.

If you want to use any shell features such as variables and redirection, then you’ll need to run those commands within an appropriate shell. For instance:

```
shell.run(["sh", "-c", "echo $PATH"])
shell.run(["sh", "-c", "ls | grep bananas"])
```

Comment: So just to be clear - what exactly is causing the failure in the command `shell.run(["echo", password, "|", "sudo", "-S", "shutdown", "-r", "now"])`. And why isn't an error thrown?